# Cobra cli fails to initialise new tool

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I have an empty dir with a go project, with only `go.mod` being present (I have run the `go mod init` command)

```
▶ cat go.mod
module github.com/myorganization/mytool

go 1.13
```

I would expect that the following command:

```
▶ ~/go/bin/cobra init mytool
```

would scaffold the area with boilerplate code so that I start creating my cli tool.

Instead I am getting the following error message:

```
▶ ~/go/bin/cobra init mytool
Error: required flag(s) "pkg-name" not set
Usage:
  cobra init [name] [flags]

Aliases:
  init, initialize, initialise, create

Flags:
  -h, --help              help for init
      --pkg-name string   fully qualified pkg name

Global Flags:
  -a, --author string    author name for copyright attribution (default "YOUR NAME")
      --config string    config file (default is $HOME/.cobra.yaml)
  -l, --license string   name of license for the project
      --viper            use Viper for configuration (default true)
```

Why is the package name needed?

Isn't this an issue in the responsibility of `go modules` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With modules, a package name is required. See the [cobra readme](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/cobra/README.md#cobra-init).