# Unable to initialize a new package using cobra init --pkg-name demo command in go

Tags: go, go-cobra, cobra

```sh
cobra init --pkg-name demo
Error: unknown flag: --pkg-name
Usage:
  cobra init [path] [flags]

Aliases:
  init, initialize, initialise, create

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for init

Global Flags:
  -a, --author string    author name for copyright attribution (default "YOUR NAME")
      --config string    config file (default is $HOME/.cobra.yaml)
  -l, --license string   name of license for the project
      --viper            use Viper for configuration
```

It shows me this issue. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an old version?

Try `cobra init demo`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137751/cobra-cli-fails-to-initialise-new-tool) and [here](https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/08/golang-cli-cobra/) for more details

Comment: I tried cobra init demo and it show Error --> cobra init demo
Error: exit status 1                                                                                                                                     and i am using latest version --> go version
go version go1.18.1